# How do I generate 6 random numbers between 1 and 6 using Java?

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers, prng

I am encountering a problem generating 6 random numbers between 1 and 6 in Java.  All the numbers have to be unique. When I enter kolon value 5, the arrays should be like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I don't want the program to generate the same two numbers.  What is wrong here?

Relevant code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter row quantity: ");

    int kolon = input.nextInt();

    Integer[][] dizi_asil = new Integer[kolon][6];

    for (int i = 0; i < kolon; i++) {
        Integer[] dizi = new Integer[6];

        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) { 

            dizi[j] = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);  

            for (int u = 0; u < 1; u++) { 

                for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) { 

                    while (dizi[k] == dizi[j]) { 
                        dizi[j] = (int) ((Math.random()* 6)  + 1);
                        u++;
                    }

                }
            }
            dizi_asil[i][j] = dizi[j];
        }
        Arrays.sort(dizi_asil[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dizi_asil.length; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < dizi_asil[i].length; k++) {
            System.out.print(dizi_asil[i][k] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: 6 unique numbers between 1 and 6 are not random. They will always be 1,2,3,4,5,6. Their order may be random, but not the numbers.

Comment: Why 4 rows if kolon=5 in your example ?

Comment: Also, you are calling `Arrays.sort(dizi_asil[i]);`. So why do you expect your arrays not to be sorted???

Comment: for example : when i run program , some times  im getting 1 2 4 5 6 6 . it's wrong i have to get always 1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: You are not looking to generate 6 random numbers, but rather a random *permutation* of the numbers 1 to 6. Try `Collection.shuffle` as others have pointed out in their answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very simple fix - replace `u++;` with `u--;`. `++` will make the loop stop, `--` will make it carry on.

Though I'd suggest something more like the below. I hope it's easy enough to understand.

```
Integer[] dizi = new Integer[6];

for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
{
  boolean isValid;
  do
  {
     dizi[j] = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
     isValid = true;
     for (int k = 0; isValid && k < j; k++)
        if (dizi[k] == dizi[j])
           isValid = false;
  }
  while (!isValid);
  dizi_asil[i][j] = dizi[j];
}
```

I'd also suggest [the Random class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), which has a `nextInt(int)` method, which is better than `(int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1)`.

But shuffling is probably a faster way to do it. Either use the API like one of the other answers or look into the [Fisher-Yates / Knuth shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) for an easy shuffle algorithm.

Answer (score 7):

create a list containing 1 to 6. then shuffle it using [Collection.shuffle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29). Then you will get random unique number

Answer (score 6):

This is an easy way:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
Collections.shuffle(list);
// you can convert it to an array if you need to.
```

Comment: for example : when i run program , some times im getting 1 2 4 5 6 6 . it's wrong i have to get always 1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: @user2204772: Then stop using the inefficient (and buggy) way and use the code snippet I provided.

Answer (score 3):

Try [`Collections.shuffle(list);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 1; i<7 ; i++)
    list.add(i);
```

Or you can do :

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6)

Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Iterate the list and get unique value each time.

Answer (score 1):

A much shorter way is to use shuffle as many have mentioned already.

```
public static void main(String... ignored) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter row quantity: ");

    List<Integer> rolls = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    for (int i = 0, rows = input.nextInt(); i < rows; i++) {
        Collections.shuffle(rolls);
        System.out.println(rolls);
    }
}
```

if you run it you get something like

```
Please enter row quantity: 
5
[5, 6, 3, 2, 4, 1]
[5, 4, 3, 6, 2, 1]
[6, 4, 2, 3, 5, 1]
[3, 1, 6, 2, 5, 4]
[4, 1, 6, 3, 5, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Imports:

```
import acm.util.RandomGenerator;
private RandomGenerator rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance();
```

Actually picking:

```
randnum = rgen.nextInt(1, 6);
```

This picks a random number between 0 and 5. You can just do this for 1 through 6:

```
randnum = rgen.nextInt(2, 7);
```

Or:

```
randnum = rgen.nextInt(1, 6);
randnum++;
```